# Redieecionamento na tela de login (HTML5/PHP)

Tags: php

Como faço o redirecionamento na tela de login onde serão 3 tipos de usuário:

1-Admin
2-Funcionário
3-Cliente

E cada um será redirecionado para páginas diferentes.

Comment: atribua um campo oculto, por exemplo: cod_tipo_usuario. Assim quando voce enviar o POST , o arquivo fará um IF ou um switch....e dependendo do resultado, já envia para a página correta

Comment: não entendi muito bem o que vc quer fazer, vc poderia editar a pergunta e acrescentar mais detalhe do problema a ela?

Comment: Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) tbm para aprender como o site funciona.

Comment: Sua pergunta está ampla demais. Veja se algo aqui ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=redirecionamento+php+is%3Aquestion - Sugiro uma lida em [Ask], e depois um clique em [edit] para você explicar melhor seu problema, com base nas orientações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar o header do PHP

```
if($tipoUsuario=='admin'){
    header('Location: url/do/admin.php');
}else if($tipoUsuario=='usuario'){
    header('Location: url/do/usuario.php');
}else if($tipoUsuario=='cliente'){
    header('Location: url/do/cliente.php');
}
```

É isso que precisa?

Comment: Era isso mesmo Neuber Oliveira, muito obrigado.